# Can this tag be [repair]ed or should we throw it away...?

Tags: discussion, tags, cleanup

I came across the tag [repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/repair) today:

- 112 questions tagged
- Excerpt:

  > Questions about repairing Ubuntu can be tagged here (after a fatal error, looping kernel panics, etc.)
- Wiki: none
- Followers: 0
- New questions during the last 12 months: 18
- Highest question score in that tag: 10

Similar to e.g. [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash) and [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze), this tag doesn't really have any informational value on its own and could probably be applied to half of our question base.

I have mostly seen it in context of boot repair, sometimes hardware (especially disks and therefore also data rescue), package management (dependencies etc) and a few other topics.

Unless you have any objections or proposals how the scope of this tag could be refined, I propose [repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/repair) should be removed.

Due its not so large size (only around 100 questions instead of over 700 for the other two mentioned examples), I also think we can successfully remove it and retag the respective questions if needed.

Comment: Indeed. There is no consistency among the posts with this tag and no specific program, command or task to which it could be consistently and exclusively applied. I don't think anyone could have a particular interest or expertise in *repair* in general. So in my opinion there is no argument for keeping the tag.

Comment: Tag destroyed. Thanks for asking :)